# result is not printing while reading a file

Tags: c

In the below program if i am giving long size=1000 results is coming but if i m taking the value through `size=ftell(fp);` its not showing any result..

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

   FILE *fp;
   long size;
   char *buff;

   fp = fopen("/home/tuhin/Desktop/abc.txt", "rb");
   fseek(fp,0l,SEEK_END);
   size=ftell(fp);
  printf("%ld",size);
   buff=calloc(1,size+1);
   fread(buff,size,1,fp);
   printf("%s",buff);
   fclose(fp);
   free(buff);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `fopen` didn't fail? Test `fp != NULL`

Comment: yah..sure becoz i have tested with long size=1000 , and its printing the result...

Comment: @xing, Thanks its working..

Comment: "its not showing any result."  --> Did `printf("%ld",size);` print anything?

Comment: amongst other problems with the posted code, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the functions: `calloc()` and  `free()`.   Then there are a couple of 'implicit conversions of value types they you should correct.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling `fseek()` and/or `ftell()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: although Visual Studio will allow the signature for `main()` to be "main()", that is not a valid signature for `main()`  suggest: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 1):

If you position the file with SEEK_END to its end, and nobody else is writing/appending to it, the fread() is trying to read something while at the end, and there is (of course) nothing to read beyond the end.

Comment: @tuhinpanda A seek back to the start, so that subsequent reads read from the start. Not sure how you can expect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with **ftell**. You are not getting the result of buff.
In order to get it use **fseek** and read the file.

**Here is code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

   FILE *fp;
   long size;
   char *buff;

   fp = fopen("abc.c", "rb");
   fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
   printf("fp:%d\n",fp);
   size=ftell(fp);
   printf("size:%ld\n",size);
   buff=calloc(1,size+1);
   fseek(fp,SEEK_SET,0);
   fread(buff,size+1,1,fp);
   printf("buff:%s",buff);
   fclose(fp);
   free(buff);

}
```